# How to remove a boundary from a emoticon in Angular. Tried it with ngx-emoji

Tags: angular, emoticons

I want to show emoticons in my Angular app, but without a boundary or border just only the emoticon.

Normal HTML code in an Angular template like this doesn't show an emoticon:

```html
<p style="font-size:100px">&#128540;</p>
<p>I will display &#128540;</p>
```

I have tried to install the `@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart` from npm.

After successful installation I tried this:

```html
<ngx-emoji [emoji]="{ id: 'face_with_rolling_eyes', skin: 2, native: true }" size="24"></ngx-emoji>
```

This shows an emoticon but with a border. I don't want the border, how to remove it?

By the way I don't need an extra library like ngx-emoi-mart in my app. I only need to show a smiley emoticon and a sad emoticon. How to do this in Angular?

I have added a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gmd9q

Comment: This may be a CSS issue. Can you provide a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Hi molamk, stackblitz added.

Comment: I also tried to add a css class in my stackblitz but it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngx-emoji adds button tag to your html. You need to add css to remove button styling. Try using this.

```css
button.emoji-mart-emoji {
    background: white;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: No it is not working, I think you are right that it has something to do with css.

Comment: Why it is a button ?   I don't need a button, I only want to show an emoticon or smiley.

Comment: @Ben since @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart is picker so it adds button while generating html to add click event.  One need to add picker.css provided by package to angular-cli.json or if not had to manually add css for button

Comment: Nikita AG thanks very much this was exactly what I was looking for. It is also documented  on npm/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart  but I did not make the link with my problem. Great, problem solved !!